# QuerySet return column name along with latest time in django python but want only time

Tags: python, django

I have written code to get latest time from 'start_time' column in my Django model in following way

```
def index(request):
    start=Location.objects.values('start_time').latest('start_time')
    end=Location.objects.values('end_time').latest('end_time')
    print (start)
    print (end)
```

Location is my model name.The output of above program is

```
{'start_time': datetime.time(11, 0)}
{'end_time': datetime.time(19, 0)}
```

I want my output as '11:00:00' and '19:00:00'
Please help me in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should format the result of your QuerySet using `strftime`

```
start['start_time'].strftime('%H:%M:%S')
end['end_time'].strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Similarly i want latest current Location .I have updated my code with      locat=Location.objects.values('Cur_Loc').latest('Cur_Loc')
But this does not give me latest location...Please Help @user7866210

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `datetime` objects. Extract time from these objects. e.g.

```
from datetime import datetime
time_now = datetime.now().time()
```

To convert to string use `strftime` function.

```
time_string = time_now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Similarly i want latest current Location .I have updated my code with locat=Location.objects.values('Cur_Loc').latest('Cur_Loc') But this does not give me latest location...Please Help @Ravi Kumar